# Using TikZ circuits library and CircuiTikZ in the same document

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

After some pocking around, I found some [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291524/using-standard-circuits-and-tikzcircuits-in-the-same-document) to use `tikz` libraries in the same document as `circuitkz` package. Or thought I did.

I like the visuals of tikz logic (and the ability to have multi-input logic gates) and the transistors in circuitikz.

I tried the above mentioned solution and it works when doing this:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering
      \begingroup
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, circuit ee IEC, huge circuit symbols, set resistor graphic = var resistor IEC graphic]
           \matrix[column sep=10mm, row sep=10mm,anchor=center]
           {
                \node [not gate] (not1) {}; \\
                \node [not gate] (not2) {}; \\
           };

           \node (a) at ([xshift=-25mm]not1.input) {$V_{in}^+$};
           \node [contact] (a1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not1.input) {};

           \node (b) at ([xshift=-25mm]not2.input) {$V_{in}^-$};
           \node [contact] (b1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not2.input) {};

           \node (x) at ([xshift=25mm]not1.output) {$V_{out}^-$};
           \node [contact] (x1) at ([xshift=10mm]not1.output) {};

           \node (z) at ([xshift=25mm]not2.output) {$V_{out}^+$};
           \node [contact] (z1) at ([xshift=10mm]not2.output) {};

           \node (en) at ([xshift=-30mm]$(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {$EN$};
           \node [contact] (en1) at ($(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {};

           \draw (en1.center) -- (not1.south) node[below right] (ennot1) {$E$};
           \draw (en1.center) -- (not2.north) node[above right] (ennot2) {$E$};

           \node [resistor={info'={$R$}}] (res1) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=10mm]not1.north){};
           \node [resistor={info={$R$}}] (res2) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=-10mm]not2.south){};

           \draw (a.east) -- (a1.center);
           \draw (a1.center) |- (res1.input);
           \draw (a1.center) -- (not1.input);

           \draw (b.east) -- (b1.center);
           \draw (b1.center) |- (res2.input);
           \draw (b1.center) -- (not2.input);

           \draw (en.east) -- (en1.center);

           \draw (not1.output) -- (x1.center);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (res1.output);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (x.west);

           \draw (not2.output) -- (z1.center);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (res2.output);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (z.west);

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \endgroup
      \caption{Some NOT gates with enable and resistors.}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \begin{center}
           \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
                \draw[thick,->] (0,0.5) --(1,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x,t)$};
                \node[] at (0,-1) {$v(x,t)$};
                \draw
                (0,0) node[anchor=east] {+}
                     to[short, o-] (1,0)
                     to[R=$Rx$] (3,0)
                     to[L=$Lx$] (5,0)
                (5,-2) to[R=$Gx$, *-*] (5,0)
                (5,0) to[short] (7,0)
                (7,-2) to[C=$Cx$, *-*] (7,0)
                (5,-2) to[short] (7,-2)
                (0,-2) node[anchor=east]{-}
                     to[short, o-] (5,-2)
                (9,0) node[anchor=west]{+}
                     to[short, o-] (7,0)
                (9,-2) node[anchor=west]{-}
                     to[short, o-] (7,-2)
                ;
                \draw[thick,->] (7,0.5) --(9,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x+ x,t)$};
                \node[] at (9,-1) {$v(x+ x,t)$};
           \end{circuitikz}
           \caption{Infinitesimal section of a transmission line.}
           \label{fig:transmission_line_section}
      \end{center}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

But, if I try to add another figure with `tikzpicture`, it exits out with errors. For example:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering
      \begingroup
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, circuit ee IEC, huge circuit symbols, set resistor graphic = var resistor IEC graphic]
           \matrix[column sep=10mm, row sep=10mm,anchor=center]
           {
                \node [not gate] (not1) {}; \\
                \node [not gate] (not2) {}; \\
           };

           \node (a) at ([xshift=-25mm]not1.input) {$V_{in}^+$};
           \node [contact] (a1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not1.input) {};

           \node (b) at ([xshift=-25mm]not2.input) {$V_{in}^-$};
           \node [contact] (b1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not2.input) {};

           \node (x) at ([xshift=25mm]not1.output) {$V_{out}^-$};
           \node [contact] (x1) at ([xshift=10mm]not1.output) {};

           \node (z) at ([xshift=25mm]not2.output) {$V_{out}^+$};
           \node [contact] (z1) at ([xshift=10mm]not2.output) {};

           \node (en) at ([xshift=-30mm]$(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {$EN$};
           \node [contact] (en1) at ($(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {};

           \draw (en1.center) -- (not1.south) node[below right] (ennot1) {$E$};
           \draw (en1.center) -- (not2.north) node[above right] (ennot2) {$E$};

           \node [resistor={info'={$R$}}] (res1) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=10mm]not1.north){};
           \node [resistor={info={$R$}}] (res2) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=-10mm]not2.south){};

           \draw (a.east) -- (a1.center);
           \draw (a1.center) |- (res1.input);
           \draw (a1.center) -- (not1.input);

           \draw (b.east) -- (b1.center);
           \draw (b1.center) |- (res2.input);
           \draw (b1.center) -- (not2.input);

           \draw (en.east) -- (en1.center);

           \draw (not1.output) -- (x1.center);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (res1.output);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (x.west);

           \draw (not2.output) -- (z1.center);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (res2.output);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (z.west);

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \endgroup
      \caption{Some NOT gates with enable and resistors.}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering
      \begingroup
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, circuit ee IEC, huge circuit symbols, set resistor graphic = var resistor IEC graphic]
           \matrix[column sep=10mm, row sep=10mm,anchor=center]
           {
                \node [not gate] (not1) {}; \\
                \node [not gate] (not2) {}; \\
           };

           \node (a) at ([xshift=-25mm]not1.input) {$V_{in}^+$};
           \node [contact] (a1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not1.input) {};

           \node (b) at ([xshift=-25mm]not2.input) {$V_{in}^-$};
           \node [contact] (b1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not2.input) {};

           \node (x) at ([xshift=25mm]not1.output) {$V_{out}^-$};
           \node [contact] (x1) at ([xshift=10mm]not1.output) {};

           \node (z) at ([xshift=25mm]not2.output) {$V_{out}^+$};
           \node [contact] (z1) at ([xshift=10mm]not2.output) {};

           \node (en) at ([xshift=-30mm]$(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {$EN$};
           \node [contact] (en1) at ($(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {};

           \draw (en1.center) -- (not1.south) node[below right] (ennot1) {$E$};
           \draw (en1.center) -- (not2.north) node[above right] (ennot2) {$E$};

           \node [resistor={info'={$R$}}] (res1) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=10mm]not1.north){};
           \node [resistor={info={$R$}}] (res2) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=-10mm]not2.south){};

           \draw (a.east) -- (a1.center);
           \draw (a1.center) |- (res1.input);
           \draw (a1.center) -- (not1.input);

           \draw (b.east) -- (b1.center);
           \draw (b1.center) |- (res2.input);
           \draw (b1.center) -- (not2.input);

           \draw (en.east) -- (en1.center);

           \draw (not1.output) -- (x1.center);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (res1.output);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (x.west);

           \draw (not2.output) -- (z1.center);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (res2.output);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (z.west);

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \endgroup
      \caption{Some NOT gates with enable and resistors.}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \begin{center}
           \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
                \draw[thick,->] (0,0.5) --(1,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x,t)$};
                \node[] at (0,-1) {$v(x,t)$};
                \draw
                (0,0) node[anchor=east] {+}
                     to[short, o-] (1,0)
                     to[R=$Rx$] (3,0)
                     to[L=$Lx$] (5,0)
                (5,-2) to[R=$Gx$, *-*] (5,0)
                (5,0) to[short] (7,0)
                (7,-2) to[C=$Cx$, *-*] (7,0)
                (5,-2) to[short] (7,-2)
                (0,-2) node[anchor=east]{-}
                     to[short, o-] (5,-2)
                (9,0) node[anchor=west]{+}
                     to[short, o-] (7,0)
                (9,-2) node[anchor=west]{-}
                     to[short, o-] (7,-2)
                ;
                \draw[thick,->] (7,0.5) --(9,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x+ x,t)$};
                \node[] at (9,-1) {$v(x+ x,t)$};
           \end{circuitikz}
           \caption{Infinitesimal section of a transmission line.}
           \label{fig:transmission_line_section}
      \end{center}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Am I doing  something wrong? If the libraries are only declared in the group, can't they be declared in another group? Is there a better solution to limiting the scope of the declared libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After carefully reading CircuiTikZ's [manual](https://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), the proper solution is to use the `compatilibity` package option and leaving TikZ libraries globaly loaded. The only downside is when using CircuiTikZ definifions, one should use an `*` before it.

For example, this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
       \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0.5) --(1,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x,t)$};
            \node[] at (0,-1) {$v(x,t)$};
            \draw
            (0,0) node[anchor=east] {+}
                 to[short, o-] (1,0)
                 to[R=$Rx$] (3,0)
                 to[L=$Lx$] (5,0)
            (5,-2) to[R=$Gx$, *-*] (5,0)
            (5,0) to[short] (7,0)
            (7,-2) to[C=$Cx$, *-*] (7,0)
            (5,-2) to[short] (7,-2)
            (0,-2) node[anchor=east]{-}
                 to[short, o-] (5,-2)
            (9,0) node[anchor=west]{+}
                 to[short, o-] (7,0)
            (9,-2) node[anchor=west]{-}
                 to[short, o-] (7,-2)
            ;
            \draw[thick,->] (7,0.5) --(9,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x+ x,t)$};
            \node[] at (9,-1) {$v(x+ x,t)$};
       \end{circuitikz}
       \caption{Infinitesimal section of a transmission line.}
       \label{fig:transmission_line_section}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Goes to this, when using the `compatibility` option:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
       \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0.5) --(1,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x,t)$};
            \node[] at (0,-1) {$v(x,t)$};
            \draw
            (0,0) node[anchor=east] {+}
                 to[*short, o-] (1,0)
                 to[*R=$Rx$] (3,0)
                 to[*L=$Lx$] (5,0)
            (5,-2) to[*R=$Gx$, *-*] (5,0)
            (5,0) to[*short] (7,0)
            (7,-2) to[*C=$Cx$, *-*] (7,0)
            (5,-2) to[*short] (7,-2)
            (0,-2) node[anchor=east]{-}
                 to[*short, o-] (5,-2)
            (9,0) node[anchor=west]{+}
                 to[*short, o-] (7,0)
            (9,-2) node[anchor=west]{-}
                 to[*short, o-] (7,-2)
            ;
            \draw[thick,->] (7,0.5) --(9,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x+ x,t)$};
            \node[] at (9,-1) {$v(x+ x,t)$};
       \end{circuitikz}
       \caption{Infinitesimal section of a transmission line.}
       \label{fig:transmission_line_section}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it is still a kludge.

Evidently, loading the libraries makes some global changes which are not removed at the end of the group.  You can however create all your mixed circuits at one time and store them (globally) in saveboxes.

You might try using externalize, or just create the images using standalone.  The best solution would be to copy the source for the TikZ components desired and rename them for use in circuitikz.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\figA}
\newsavebox{\figB}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
      \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
      \global\setbox\figA=\hbox{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, circuit ee IEC, huge circuit symbols, set resistor graphic = var resistor IEC graphic]
           \matrix[column sep=10mm, row sep=10mm,anchor=center]
           {
                \node [not gate] (not1) {}; \\
                \node [not gate] (not2) {}; \\
           };

           \node (a) at ([xshift=-25mm]not1.input) {$V_{in}^+$};
           \node [contact] (a1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not1.input) {};

           \node (b) at ([xshift=-25mm]not2.input) {$V_{in}^-$};
           \node [contact] (b1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not2.input) {};

           \node (x) at ([xshift=25mm]not1.output) {$V_{out}^-$};
           \node [contact] (x1) at ([xshift=10mm]not1.output) {};

           \node (z) at ([xshift=25mm]not2.output) {$V_{out}^+$};
           \node [contact] (z1) at ([xshift=10mm]not2.output) {};

           \node (en) at ([xshift=-30mm]$(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {$EN$};
           \node [contact] (en1) at ($(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {};

           \draw (en1.center) -- (not1.south) node[below right] (ennot1) {$E$};
           \draw (en1.center) -- (not2.north) node[above right] (ennot2) {$E$};

           \node [resistor={info'={$R$}}] (res1) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=10mm]not1.north){};
           \node [resistor={info={$R$}}] (res2) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=-10mm]not2.south){};

           \draw (a.east) -- (a1.center);
           \draw (a1.center) |- (res1.input);
           \draw (a1.center) -- (not1.input);

           \draw (b.east) -- (b1.center);
           \draw (b1.center) |- (res2.input);
           \draw (b1.center) -- (not2.input);

           \draw (en.east) -- (en1.center);

           \draw (not1.output) -- (x1.center);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (res1.output);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (x.west);

           \draw (not2.output) -- (z1.center);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (res2.output);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (z.west);

      \end{tikzpicture}}%
      \global\setbox\figB=\hbox{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, circuit ee IEC, huge circuit symbols, set resistor graphic = var resistor IEC graphic]
           \matrix[column sep=10mm, row sep=10mm,anchor=center]
           {
                \node [not gate] (not1) {}; \\
                \node [not gate] (not2) {}; \\
           };

           \node (a) at ([xshift=-25mm]not1.input) {$V_{in}^+$};
           \node [contact] (a1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not1.input) {};

           \node (b) at ([xshift=-25mm]not2.input) {$V_{in}^-$};
           \node [contact] (b1) at ([xshift=-10mm]not2.input) {};

           \node (x) at ([xshift=25mm]not1.output) {$V_{out}^-$};
           \node [contact] (x1) at ([xshift=10mm]not1.output) {};

           \node (z) at ([xshift=25mm]not2.output) {$V_{out}^+$};
           \node [contact] (z1) at ([xshift=10mm]not2.output) {};

           \node (en) at ([xshift=-30mm]$(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {$EN$};
           \node [contact] (en1) at ($(not1.south)!0.5!(not2.north)$) {};

           \draw (en1.center) -- (not1.south) node[below right] (ennot1) {$E$};
           \draw (en1.center) -- (not2.north) node[above right] (ennot2) {$E$};

           \node [resistor={info'={$R$}}] (res1) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=10mm]not1.north){};
           \node [resistor={info={$R$}}] (res2) at ([xshift=2mm, yshift=-10mm]not2.south){};

           \draw (a.east) -- (a1.center);
           \draw (a1.center) |- (res1.input);
           \draw (a1.center) -- (not1.input);

           \draw (b.east) -- (b1.center);
           \draw (b1.center) |- (res2.input);
           \draw (b1.center) -- (not2.input);

           \draw (en.east) -- (en1.center);

           \draw (not1.output) -- (x1.center);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (res1.output);
           \draw (x1.center) |- (x.west);

           \draw (not2.output) -- (z1.center);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (res2.output);
           \draw (z1.center) |- (z.west);

      \end{tikzpicture}}
 \endgroup

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering
      \usebox{\figA}      
      \caption{Some NOT gates with enable and resistors.}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering
      \usebox{\figB}
      \caption{Some NOT gates with enable and resistors.}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \begin{center}
           \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
                \draw[thick,->] (0,0.5) --(1,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x,t)$};
                \node[] at (0,-1) {$v(x,t)$};
                \draw
                (0,0) node[anchor=east] {+}
                     to[short, o-] (1,0)
                     to[R=$Rx$] (3,0)
                     to[L=$Lx$] (5,0)
                (5,-2) to[R=$Gx$, *-*] (5,0)
                (5,0) to[short] (7,0)
                (7,-2) to[C=$Cx$, *-*] (7,0)
                (5,-2) to[short] (7,-2)
                (0,-2) node[anchor=east]{-}
                     to[short, o-] (5,-2)
                (9,0) node[anchor=west]{+}
                     to[short, o-] (7,0)
                (9,-2) node[anchor=west]{-}
                     to[short, o-] (7,-2)
                ;
                \draw[thick,->] (7,0.5) --(9,0.5) node[anchor=south east] {$i(x+ x,t)$};
                \node[] at (9,-1) {$v(x+ x,t)$};
           \end{circuitikz}
           \caption{Infinitesimal section of a transmission line.}
           \label{fig:transmission_line_section}
      \end{center}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```